# Translation of "User account is disabled."

Tags: symfony

I need to translate (and override for English language) the "User account is disabled." message displayed when a user tries to login with a disabled user account.

I've found this message in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserChecker.php

It seems that this message is not part of any xliff or yml translation file. Does that mean that we have to override this class to change/translate this message ?

Is there any cleaner solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uncaught exceptions are usually rendered by the [ExceptionController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php) in the TwigBundle and then rendered using one of the templates in [TwigBundle/Resources/Resources/views/Exception](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception) depending on the request - most likely [exception.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception.html.twig).

In this case those exceptions all extend [AuthenticationException](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/AuthenticationException.php) and are therefore caught by  [Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php#L97) during the authentication process.

The exception will trigger the SecurityContext to contain an authentication error which will ( in the example of FOSUserBundle ) be passed to your login form as [a variable called error](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L20). This variable will then be rendered ( and translated using the trans filter ) in [the login template](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig).

You can just add new translations for these messages in app/Resources/translations or app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/translation or one of the other locations translations are being searched for by symfony ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-locations-and-naming-conventions)) - make sure you are using the right [translation domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#using-message-domains) - which is `FOSUserBundle` in case you're using the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @nifr for your answer. I was almost there except I did not take into consideration the translation domain. It works now that my translation file has been renamed from security.en.xlf to FOSUserBundle.en.xlf and contains the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>User account is disabled.</source>
                <target>The actual error label I wanted...</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
'User account is disabled.': Ce compte n'est pas activé.
```

into MyBundle/Resources/translations/security.fr.yml worked for me.